# Input EditText value into a Button in Next Activity

Tags: java, android

How can I pass the input text in the `EditText` goes to the Button text field in the new activity. I want to show a text on `Button` by using the  EditText  of the previous activity. but how? thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Provide more details !

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to pass data between activities.

In your first activity get `Edittext`'s text as string by calling `edittext.getText().toString()`.

Then use:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, FindAndroidActivity.class);
i.putExtra("KEY",YourData);
```

In your second activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString("KEY");
}
```

Then set button's text as:

```
buton.setText(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity:

```
intent.putExtra("text", editText.getText().toString());
```

In the second activity:

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
((Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout)).setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use My code as per your requirement

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private EditText edt;
    private Button btn;
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);     
        edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v==btn)
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("text",edt.getText().toString());
        }

    }

}
```

**And This is Your Second Activity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String text=getIntent().getStringExtra("text");

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 

        btn.setText(text);  
    }
}
```